# How to add an array of elements in a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and I want to allow the user to add as many input boxes as he/she desires and then post the form back to a php file and read it in php variables. The code I was trying to add doesn't really get me to add elements like an array. Can someone please guide?

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="up_form">
    <input id="instruction1" name="instruction1" type="input"></input>
    <input id="next" type="button">Next</input>
    <input id="recip_up_submit" type="submit" value="Save Recipe" name="submit">
</form>
```

Jquery code is"

```
$("#next").click(function(){$("#instruction1").after("</br><input id='inst[]'></input>");});
```

Comment: `id='inst[]'` should be `name='inst[]'`

Comment: u are going to send a bunch of newly created input, `name=inst[]` tells when it is submitted to the server it gona be an array.

Comment: just do `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';` in process.php u wil see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your js u had `<input id='inst[]'>` as u see u done even have a handler to send to php to catch so it not being submitted as it dosen't have a `name` attribute if u put `name=inst` it will send only one input which u add dynamically by js. But if u do `name=inst[]` all the input value will be send to the server as an array. i hop u got it.

HTML:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="up_form">
    <input id="instruction1" name="instruction1" type="input" />
    <input id="next" type="button" value="Next">
    <input id="recip_up_submit" type="submit" value="Save Recipe" name="submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#instruction1").after("</br><input name='inst[]' />");
});
```